# Proving Equivalence: Lebesgue Measurable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I need help understanding the proof of the following theorem:

> For an arbitrary subset $E$ of $R$, the following statements are equivalent:
>
> i. $E$ is Lebesgue measurable in the sense of Caratheodory.
>
> ii. Given $\epsilon>0$ we can determine an open set $G\subset R$ with $E\subset G$ and $\mu^*(G-E)<\epsilon.$
>
> iii. Given $\epsilon>0$ we can determine a closed set $F\subset R$ with $F\subset E$ and $\mu^*(E-F)<\epsilon.$
>
> iv. There is a $G_\delta$ set $B_1$ with $E\subset B_1$ and $\mu^*(B_1-E)=0$.

I"m having problem understanding the implications $(ii)\implies (iii)$ and $(iii)\implies (iv)$.

The proof given for $(ii)\implies (iii)$ is:

"Apply part (ii) to $E^C$. We have $E^C\subset G$ and $\mu^*(G-E^C)<\epsilon$. But then $G^C\subset E$. $\mu^*(E-G^C)=\mu^*(G-E^C)$ and with $F=G^C$, the argument is complete."

I tried drawing the sets and it does not look like $G^C$ will always become a subset of $E$. Also, why is $\mu^*(E-G^C)=\mu^*(G-E^C)$?

The proof for $(iii)\implies (iv)$ is this:

"Let $E\subset R$ and apply part $(iii)$ to $E^C$. We have a sequence of closed sets $(F_k)$ so that $F_k\subset E^C$ and $\mu^*(E^C-F_k)<1/k$. Let $B_1=\bigcap F^C_k$. $B_1$ is a $G_\delta$ set, $E\subset B_1$, and $$\mu^*(B_1-E)=\mu^*(E^C-\bigcup F_k)\leq \mu^*(E^C-F_k)<1/k$$ $k=1,2,...$ Therefore $\mu^*(B_1-E)=0$."

Why did we have a sequence of closed sets? Is it because for every $\epsilon>0$ we can find a closed set? Why is $\mu^*(E^C-F_k)$ less than $1/k$? Shouldn't it be $\epsilon$? I can't also grasp the inequality in the last line.

I hope someone could help me understand this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question,
$$
E\setminus G^c = E\cap G = G\setminus E^c
$$
For the second, the author is repeatedly applying $(iii)$ to $E^c$ for different values of $\epsilon$ :

For $\epsilon = 1$, you get a closed set $F_1$ such that $\mu^{\ast}(E^c\setminus F_1) < 1$.

For $\epsilon = 1/2$, you get a closed set $F_2$ such that $\mu^{\ast}(E^c\setminus F_2) < 1/2$.

Repeating this process (by induction, if you like), for $\epsilon = 1/k$, you get a closed set $F_k$ such that $\mu^{\ast}(E^c\setminus F_k)<1/k$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For $(iii)$ couldn't I just use $\epsilon$ for all $F_i$'s? In the end I will have $\mu^*(E^C-F_k)<\epsilon$ which would also imply that $\mu^*(B_1-E)=0$.